# How to create one array from two arrays according to criteria

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$generated_errors = array(
          'required'  => 'fieldname', 
          'min'  => 'fieldname', 
          'max'  => 'fieldname');
$all_errors = array(
          'required' => ' is required', 
          'min' => ' must be at least 6 character', 
          'max' => ' must be at maximum 20 character', 
          'onlynumber' => ' must be only numbers', 
          'email' => ' must be valid email');
```

I want to 1 array (according to `$generated_errors`) from both of them as:

```
$errors = array(
          'required' => 'Field name is required', 
          'min' => 'Field name must be at least 6 character', 
          'max' => 'Field name must be maximum 20 character');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over `$generated_errors` and enrich it with `$all_errors` values:

```
for ($generated_erros as $key => $value) {
    $erros[$key] = $value . $all_errors[$key];
}
```

Comment: foreach ($generated_errors as $key => $value) {
    $errors[$key] = $value . $all_errors[$key];
}
print_r($errors)
This is working

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this

```
$errors =array();
for ($generated_erros as $key => $value) {
    $errors[$key] = $value . $all_errors[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do some like this:

```
$result = array();
array_walk($generated_errors, function($item, $value) use(&$all_errors, &$result){
       array_push($result, [$key => ($generated_errors[$key] . $all_errors[$key])]);
});
```

I haven't tested the above code, but I think it works. I guess it's faster than the `for loop`. Because in `for loop` there are a lot of deductions which reduce the speed (though not very much).

Comment: I am new to php so i only can understand ready scripts but i can't correct it :(

Comment: I already have corrected it. I know that is the responsibility of a person who answers to put a healthy code. @Newmaster